# BizTalk 2010 Conditional Mapping Issue (from two different recurring source nodes to same destination node)

Tags: xslt, sum, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have an EDI 810 file, from which I have to conditionally map certain values from two different repeating `SAC` nodes, which occur multiple times in different spots in the document. Please note that the `SAC_2` occurs at a lower level when compared to the `SAC_3` node. A sample fragment of the source document looks like this:

```
<ns1:IT1Loop1>
  <ns1:SLNLoop1>
    <ns1:SAC_2>
      <SAC01>C</ID>
      <SAC05>3443</Name>
      <SAC15>Service A</ID>
    </ns1:SAC_2>
  </ns1:SLNLoop1>
  <ns1:SLNLoop1>
    <ns1:SAC_2>
      <SAC01>C</ID>
      <SAC05>120</Name>
      <SAC15>Service B</ID>
    </ns1:SAC_2>
  </ns1:SLNLoop1>
  <ns1:SLNLoop1>
    <ns1:SAC_2>
      <SAC01>A</ID>
      <SAC05>243</Name>
      <SAC15>Service D</ID>
    </ns1:SAC_2>
  </ns1:SLNLoop1>
</ns1:IT1Loop1>
<ns1:IT1Loop1>
  <ns1:SLNLoop1>
    <ns1:SAC_2>
      <SAC01>A</ID>
      <SAC05>567</Name>
      <SAC15>Service C</ID>
    </ns1:SAC_2>
  </ns1:SLNLoop1>
  <ns1:SLNLoop1>
    <ns1:SAC_2>
      <SAC01>F</ID>
      <SAC05>4558</Name>
      <SAC15>Service M</ID>
    </ns1:SAC_2>
  </ns1:SLNLoop1>
</ns1:IT1Loop1>
<ns1:SACLoop2>
  <ns1:SAC_3>
    <SAC01>A</ID>
    <SAC05>-1234</Name>
    <SAC15>Adjustment</ID>
  </ns1:SAC_3>
</ns1:SACLoop2>
<ns1:SACLoop2>
  <ns1:SAC_3>
    <SAC01>D</ID>
    <SAC05>24567</Name>
    <SAC15>Balance Forward</ID>
  </ns1:SAC_3>
</ns1:SACLoop2>
```

Here are the conditions: 
From the `SAC_2`, I need to map the values of the `SAC05` (to `Amount`) and `SAC15` (to `Description`) elements, IF `SAC_2/SAC01` has the values `"C"` or `"A"`.
From the `SAC_3`, I need to map the values of the `SAC05` (to `Amount`) and `SAC15` (to `Description`) elements, IF `SAC_3/SAC01` has the values `"C"` or `"A"` AND the `SAC15 != "Balance Forward"`.
So it is supposed to generate as many `"MeasureItems"` as there are any of these segments with criteria fulfilled.
Here is what the output should look like for the sample input:

```
<Root>
  <HeaderItems>
  ...
  </HeaderItems>
  <MeasureItems>
    <Description>Service A</Description>
    <Amount>3443</Amount>
  </MeasureItems>
  <MeasureItems>
    <Description>Service B</Description>
    <Amount>120</Amount>
  </MeasureItems>
  <MeasureItems>
    <Description>Service D</Description>
    <Amount>243</Amount>
  </MeasureItems>
  <MeasureItems>
    <Description>Service C</Description>
    <Amount>567</Amount>
  </MeasureItems>
  <MeasureItems>
    <Description>Adjustment</Description>
    <Amount>-1234</Amount>
  </MeasureItems>
  <ReadItems>
  ...
  </ReadItems>
</Root>
```

There is no way to do this easily through only functoids alone so I have tried a combination of the `EqualTo`, `NotEqualTo`, `LogicalOR`, `ValueMapping` functoids along with the scripting functoid (inline C#) to choose between inputs (if conditions held true), but nothing gave me the correct output.

Image: [image: http://i68.tinypic.com/2dj5d2c.jpg]

With this arrangement (shown in image) functoid I would always get everything mapped correctly from the `SAC_2` repetitions but it would completely ignore the `SAC_3` elements.

And with inline XSLT it would always map only from the first occurrence of `SAC_2` segment, from each recurring `IT1Loop1` parent. And, of course, it would completely ignore the `SAC_3` elements again.

Here is one version of the inline XSLT code I used:

```
<xsl:element name = "Description">

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=".//*[local-name()='SAC_2']/SAC01 = 'C' or .//*[local-name()='SAC_2']/SAC01 = 'A'">
      <xsl:value-of select = ".//*[local-name()='SAC_2']/SAC15[preceding-sibling::SAC01='C' or preceding-sibling::SAC01='A']"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test=".//*[local-name()='SAC_3']/SAC01 = 'C' and not(.//*[local-name()='SAC_3']/SAC15 = 'Balance Forward')">
      <xsl:value-of select = ".//*[local-name()='SAC_3']/SAC15[preceding-sibling::SAC01='C' or preceding-sibling::SAC01='A']"/>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:element>
```

I'm guessing switch statements and loops don't work the same way in XSLT as they do in other languages. Also, I tried the same logic through inline C# alone too. It did not yield correct results.

I'm quite sure there should be a way to do this using inline XSLT or some other custom code solution.

Additionally, I don't understand why the `SAC_3` elements keep getting ignored.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a looping functoid and a couple logical functoids.  Connect the `ITLoop1` and the `SACLoop2` as inputs to the looping functoid, and have it output to your destination repeating node (`MeasurementItems`).  Then like `SAC05` and `SAC15` to the correct destinations.  Finally, add some `Equals` functoids to the map, with `SAC1` as the input, 'A' as the second parameter, and output to the `MeasurementItems`.  Add the same functoid for both `SAC1` elements, and another set that uses `C` as the second input.  See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561739.aspx) for more information.

If you want to do this in XSLT, it will have to generate the entire `MeasurementItems` node, which may or may not be more difficult than its worth (or might be worth jus tdoing the whole map in XSLT).  Your template would look something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//ns1:SAC_2[SAC01='A' or SAC01='C'] | //ns1:SAC_3[(SAC01 = 'A' or SAC01= 'C') and SAC15 != 'Balance Forward']" xmlns:ns1='REPLACE_WITH_REAL_NAMESPACE'>
  <Amount>
    <xsl:value-of select="SAC05" />  
  </Amount>
  <Description>
    <xsl:value-of select="SAC15" />  
  </Description>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! The arrangement using the looping functoids worked perfectly.

Comment: Although, for the sake of my own learning/understanding could you explain this XSLT issue? - The XSLT template that you provided, did not work and unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with using templates in XSLT. I kept getting 2 errors, one saying that the QName " is invalid, even though I changed the namespace and the other saying that the template has no name. I know that the QName refers to the qualified name but I don't really know what to do to fix these. Could you explain this?

Comment: This template would have to be refactored a bit to use in a scripting functoid - probably put it in a call template functoid and use a for-each instead of a match.  Not sure about the QName error, but that's likely the cause of the other error.  I had this template more in mind as a rough example of what it would look like in a full XSLT file